# Batch file to start new javaw process not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, javaw

I'm new to writing Windows batch file. I have the following batch file to start a new javaw process and redirect the output of the commands in the batch file to a log file.

```
@echo OFF

call :sub >start-demo.jar.cmd.log
exit /b

:sub
 echo starting demo.jar ..
 start "" javaw -jar demo.jar
 echo done ..
```

It's working fine and I can see that the output is redirected correctly to the log file and the javaw process is also started with a new process id when I execute the batch file.

Here is the output redirected to the log file after the batch file is executed.

```
starting demo.jar ..
done ..
```

However, when I try to edit or delete the log file after the batch file is executed, it says that the action can't be completed because the file is open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary.

Only after killing the javaw process I'm able to edit or delete the log file.

Not sure why this is happening and how to fix this. My expectation is that once the javaw process is started successfully, I should be able to edit or delete the log file. Is this correct?

My OS is Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to edit a log file that is currently being written to?

Comment: Does that mean once the javaw process is started, the log file will still be attached to the  javaw process until it is killed? I just want to redirect the output of all commands in the batch file to the log file, including the output of the start command. I can see that the start command immediately returns control once it's executed.

Comment: Honestly, I've never seen redirection used this way before, but since you're redirecting the `call` and you aren't using the `/wait` flag with `start`, I'm a little surprised that java is taking ownership of the log file at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added more details to the questions to make it more clear. Javaw is indeed taking ownership of the log file. It's confusing for me too..

Comment: Why aren't you using `java.exe`? `javaw.exe` is not a console program!

Comment: javaw.exe is more suitable for running java as a back-end process as it's not attached to a console. My requirement is to use javaw.exe.